# Facebook. Comment Plugin. Dark scheme styles problems

Tags: css, facebook

i have encountered with problem(bug). I have the simple web page with the FB comment plugin. The problem is the social comment plugin with "dark" color scheme looks wrong. I can not imagine how to get arround this problem.

You can see how it must looks [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) (choose "dark" scheme in options)

[image]

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: I have found out that ".dark_background" class and appropriate css styles do not apply to top container <fb:comment>. I can set up it mannualy and it get dark. I reported this bug to FB and i'm going to get response.

Answer (score 0):

It actually looks fine to me. Try refreshing your CSS by clearing your browser cache.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly it haven't helped. I tried it out on others computers.

Comment: Strange, it works for me in both. Have you tried doing it in an incognito window? How have you cleared your cache?

Comment: i could get link to you see yourself